# How to yank words between dots on multiple lines in VIM?

Tags: vim

I try to find the best way to copy (all occurrences) and paste (all the occurrences somewhere else) the second word in between the dots in this example case with vim (without plugins):

```
1 somename.xyz.something
2 so.someday.zzzz
3 text.example.fese.efsse
```

The result after I paste it somewhere else:

```
5 xyz
6 someday
7 example
```

Comment: Please define "copy and paste" and show us what you tried.

Comment: sorry ive updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would copy the lines in question (e.g. `yip` or through visual mode) and paste them to the desired location, so you'd get:

```
somename.xyz.something
so.someday.zzzz
text.example.fese.efsse

somename.xyz.something
so.someday.zzzz
text.example.fese.efsse
```

And then delete the unwanted parts. For example by selecting them in visual mode and running `:'<,'>normal 0df.f.D`, resulting in:

```
somename.xyz.something
so.someday.zzzz
text.example.fese.efsse

xyz
someday
example
```

Comment: is it possible to do it all at once. For example visualise all relevant lines and copy every occurrence, so that i can paste all the word somewhere else at once

Comment: Hm, I missed that part :-\ How do you want the paste it? As a collection of lines containing one word each?

Comment: ive updated my question sorry for the not so explicit question

Comment: thank you! Sadly ideavim doesnt support normal, i have to do it with macro ...

Comment: So, was the question about Vim or Ideavim? Ideavim is far from covering every Vim feature so there is really no point in asking about vim when you really want an Ideavim solution.

Comment: yeah but i have no different choice, can only use ideavim... but privatly its good to know how to in real vim